# What is javascript function that opposite of indexof()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is javascript function that opposite of indexof() ?

In this my code when you press button. It's will show `3` [from `indexof(".")`].

But I want function that opposite of `indexof()`, That show me `2` [decimal]

http://jsfiddle.net/TyV3s/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "150.20";
    var n = str.indexOf(".");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So basically you only want to know if there are 2 digits after the dot. Right?

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat unsurprisingly, [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) will help here.

The only catch is that it still numbers from the end of the string, so you would have to do something like `str.length - str.lastIndexOf(".") - 1` to get the `2` you are looking for. There is no built-in function for this.

Comment: `lastIndexOf` starts from the end, but still counts from the start of the string. In this case the `str.length` is 6. And 6-3 = 3. So you need to add another -1 (for the dot that doesn´t count for the length) to get the 2

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
str.split(".")[1].length;
```

You can split the string at the `"."` with `.split()` method and get the first index with `[1]` and calculate the length of it.

---

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TyV3s/4/)

---

As *Der Vampyr* commented so i think there should be so you can update it with this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "150.22";
    var dot = str.indexOf(".");
    var n = (dot != -1) ? str.split(".")[1].length : "This value does not have decimals.";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

[Another Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/TyV3s/6/)

Comment: I think this is a good solution. It shows if there are 2 digits after the dot or not. (Maybe another check is necessary, because it maybe look like this "123". So another check if `indexOf(".") > 0` is useful)